# Flutter Splash Screen on android does flicker and resize

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

The app starts and the splash screen renders my image but then flickers and resizes it when android:gravity="center" is set.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`<meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
        android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>`

inside your  in the AndroidManifest.xml file